# A properties file doesn't get delete while uninstall and doesn't rewrite at the time of installation over the previously installed location

Tags: install4j

A properties file doesn't get delete while uninstall which happens when we try to install the installer at the existing installed location. It neither delete it while uninstall nor update it while installing. It gives the message(see the attached image.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFqTt.png))

Here are some logs related to delete file action:-

[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.DeleteFileAction [ID 1454]: Execute action
       Property rollbackSupported: true
       Property backupForRollback: true
       Property recursive: true
       Property showProgress: false
       Property showFileNames: true
       Property files: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Application_11.5\JRE,  C:\Program Files (x86)\Application_11.5\Application.properties]
       Property directoryFilter: null
       Property fileFilter: null

```
   Backing up C:\Program Files (x86)\Application_11.5\JRE\bin\awt.dll
   Backing up C:\Program Files (x86)\Application_11.5\JRE\bin\bci.dll
   Backing up C:\Program Files (x86)\Application_11.5\JRE\bin\client\jvm.dll
   Backing up C:\Program Files (x86)\Application_11.5\JRE\bin\client\Xusage.txt
   Backing up C:\Program Files (x86)\Application_11.5\JRE\bin\dcpr.dll
   .....
```

Backing up C:\Program Files (x86)\Application_11.5\SiteManager.properties
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.DeleteFileAction [ID 1454]: The file C:\Program Files (x86)\Application_11.5\Application.properties cannot be deleted

Answer (score 0):

> The file C:\Program Files (x86)\Application_11.5\Application.properties cannot be deleted

This means that something has a lock on this file. You can check with [process explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) which process that it.